# Create custom severity messages in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using JSF messages to show the **error/warning/info** messages into my web application. Also I use [`<p:messages>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/messages.jsf) to render them in the browser with different styles.

Nevertheless, I need to create a new style for some of my messages, keeping the rest of them as they are right now. In other words, I need to create an **ok** severity for my JSF messages, which will display the info in a green box with a tick.

Although I've been looking at library classes, it seems not to be an straight forwarded way to achieve that. Severities are stored into `FacesMessages$Severity` class as an enumeration and have a private constructor. Do I have to override the source code directly?

Comment: The info severity is not for the "ok" purpose? When you do some action, if it does output info, normally this is when everything was fine no?

Comment: I want to add a message when user introduces an email address. 'Ok' will be for valid address and 'error' for invalid. I wanted to differ between that message type and informative one.

Comment: I wonder if this is still the case in JSF 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible without hacking the JSF API/impl, no.

Just reuse the `INFO` severity, or abuse the one apparently unused by you: `FATAL`. Or, if the functional requirement is purely presentational, throw in some JS/jQuery/CSS to achieve it.

A drastic alternative would be reinventing the JSF message system with custom message wrappers and custom message components.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer Balus. Is it done like that by JSF for any specific reason or could be a future improvement for them to add more flexible messaging classes?

Comment: I agree that the design of faces messages is subject for improvements. It's also somewhat a heritage from old JSF 1.x ages. But, on the other hand, it's not possible to randomly specify custom attributes like `okStyle` or `okClass` on existing JSF message components without manipulating/extending the component and renderer.

Comment: Any chance we see that feature in the feature? Adding custom severity levels? Do you think it would help to open a feature request?